# Spyder IPython Freezes with n_jobs?

Tags: python, ipython, scikit-learn, spyder

I've been playing around with some sklearn tutorials using anaconda, but have run into a strange issue when working in Spyder.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

x = np.random.uniform(1,100,1000)
y = np.log(x) + np.random.normal(0,0.3,1000)

# If running in Spyder IPython Console, it will freeze if n_jobs != 1
# Runs fine in all other situations, including a Spyder Python console.
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2, verbose=3)
clf.fit(x.reshape((1000,1)), y)
```

In particular, any attempt to fit a model with more than one thread will hang (no output produced) if run in the IPython console.

Everything works as expected in a regular Python console.

Pretty annoying, and fairly confusing at first.

Comment: There have been other people who have reported this - it is likely an issue between IPython's backend and joblib. Thanks for the report. Is there any console output that seems useful? A backtrace might help us track this down

Comment: I updated to sklearn 0.15.0 (from 0.14.1) which resolved this issue. No interesting output was created, but from what I remember the default message in the IP kernel would get repeated as soon as I tried to run the fit.

Comment: This was answered by Olivier Grisel in reddit. The problem lies in the use of the `multiprocessing` module by `RandomForestRegressor` and a faulty `os.fork` build of Anaconda.